# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку подключалась страница?

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте ХешКод. Есть кнопка, надо сделать, чтобы при нажатии 1-й раз, показывалась страница, а если страница уже открыта, то при нажатии на кнопку страница скрывалась, или проще говоря, на явном примере на ХешКоде, нажимаете комментировать - появляется поле для ввода, а когда нажимаете отмена, она скрывается. Вот примерно такое надо реализовать, а на чём и как не знаю? Была сделана попытка:

```
<input type = "submit" value = "Кто онлайн" onlick = "<? include('online.php'); ?>" />
```

Но не работает.

Comment: Жесть какая )) Изучайте php, изучайте html. Сейчас все в куче, вот и не работает. А то что вы хотите сделать, делается с помощью javascript, а в современном мире на js фреймворке, обычно на jquery. Но вам до этого еще далеко.

Comment: Ээээ ну да, я новичек пока, но я думаю что это не настолько сложно что новичку не под силу?

Comment: У вас мешанина JavaScript и PHP. На JavaScript легко сделать скрытие и открытие отдельного блока.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может нужно скрыть/показать блок на странице?

```
div{width:200px;height:200px;
    border:2px solid #999;
    background:#CCC}
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="fn()" />
<div id ="blog">this blog</div>
<script>
    function fn(){
        blog=document.getElementById('blog').style;
        if(blog.display=='none'){
            blog.display='block'
        }
        else{
            blog.display='none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Да УРА! Это работает, спасибо большое!